# Splitting string and creating variable using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a string `28,16OB4N7L8O4L` using two arrays I had split into separate variables.

```
hrs1 hrs2 hrs3 hrs4 hrs5 hrs6 hrs7    
28   16   1     4   7    8    4

cd1  cd2  cd3  cd4  cd5  cd6  cd7

,    O    B    N    L    O    L
```

Now I want to summarize across variables, if same value repeats in character variable in the above example `'O'` and`'L'` are repeated, in that case I want to merge as one and add the respective hrs.

Output should be:

```
,  O  B  N  L       -COLUMN  
28 24 1  4  11      -VALUES
```

Comment: Would you accept a solution where you transpose the data?  That is, instead of starting with 14 variables (hrs1-hrs7 and cd1-cd7), transpose it be to just two variables, hrs and cd.  In that structure, collapsing to group by cd and sum hrs within each group is straight forward.

Comment: How do you get hrs3=1 from the original string?

Comment: When there are two consecutive characters I inserted 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of transposing to normalized (long skinny format).  I added a second sample record.

```
data have;
  input id hrs1-hrs7 (cd1-cd7) ($1.);
  cards;
1 28 16 1 4 7 8 4 ,OBNLOL
2 1  2  3 4 5 6 7 AAAABBB
;
run;

data tran (keep=id hr cd) / view=tran ;
  set have ;
  array hrs{*} hrs1-hrs7 ;
  array cds{*} cd1-cd7 ;
  do i=1 to dim(hrs) ;
    hr=hrs{i} ;
    cd=cds{i} ;
    output ;
  end ;
run ;

proc sql ;
  select id, cd, sum(hr)
  from tran
  group by id, cd
  ;
quit ;
```

Returns:

```
id  cd
________________
 1  ,         28
 1  B          1
 1  L         11
 1  N          4
 1  O         24
 2  A         10
 2  B         18
```